# ReactJS - Conditional rendering not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Basically, the code snippet below is for the Close/Edit icon: Once clicked in "Close" mode, it will change to the "Edit" icon and pass the `rowId` and a "1" parameter in the `handleEdit` function; and, once in "Edit" mode, it will pass the `rowId` and a "0" parameter.

The problem is that it only goes to the condition of `editClose === 1`, although it updates the `editDeleteTag` to `1`; it never seems to render the `stylesEditOptions` icon along with it's condition.

I'm new to React, so I might be missing something here.

**childComponenent.jsx**

```
funcEdit = (editClose) => {
    if (editClose === 0) {

        return (<div className={styles.editOptions}>
            <Input type="button" className={styles.closeIcon} onClick={() => this.props.handleEdit(rowIndex, 1)} />
        </div >)

    } else {
        return (<div className={styles.editOptions}>
            <Input type="button" className={styles.EditIcon} onClick={() => this.props.handleEdit(rowIndex, 0)} />        
        </div >)
    }
}

render()

    let locArr = [...this.state.mainArray];

    For looop .... {
    
        if (locArr[i].editOrDeleteTag === 0) {
            locArr[i].editOrDelete = this.funcEdit(1);    
        } else {
            locArr[i].editOrDelete = this.funcEdit(0);
        }
    }

return(
        ...
        <BootstrapTable data={locArr}
        ...
    )
```

**parentComponent.jsx**

```
    handleEdit = (rowId, toggle) => {
      
    let locArr = [...this.state.mainArray];
    locArr[rowId.rowIndex].editOrDeleteTag = toggle

    this.setState({ mainArray : locArr });

    };
```

Comment: Please provide syntactically correct & complete code. If I had to guess anything it may be an enclosure of stale state in the saved `Input` components and callbacks passed to the table. If you can update your question to include a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example it may become more clear what is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is the fact that you are mutating the state.

When making state changes to a nested object you need to update all parent elements.

So in your `handleEdit` try to use

```
locArr[rowId.rowIndex] = { 
  ...locArr[rowId.rowIndex],
  editOrDeleteTag: toggle
};
```

instead of

```
locArr[rowId.rowIndex].editOrDeleuteTag = toggle;
```